# Building Boost System library with CMake?

Tags: c++, boost, cross-platform, cmake

I am attempting to integrate the boost chrono library into a project built with cmake.  The chrono library can be switched to a "headers only" inclusion with by defining `BOOST_CHRONO_HEADER_ONLY`.  This is convenient, because I don't need to incorporate that library into cmake.  The hangup is that chrono appears to depend on boost system, which does need to be built.  I'd like to complete this integration with the following goals:

- Build on Linux and Windows
- Build "out of the box" without having boost installed

It seems the way to do this is to make a CMakeLists.txt to build the boost system library.  Being relatively new at CMake, and boost I have little idea what I'd be getting into.  Would it be reasonable to "translate" the jamfile into CMake?  I have seen that there is a CMake boost project on Gitorious, but it appears to be a few versions behind.

Comment: looking into the CMakeified release for hints... https://github.com/pocb/boost, it's up to Boost 1.48.0  Release Notes for 1.49.0 don't mention the system library.  This might do the job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could trigger the build using CMake [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_command)s and a [`add_custom_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_custom_target). Have a target that depends on one of the built files, and then custom commands to call the build.

The other way to do this is with the [ExternalProject](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module%3aExternalProject) module, this simplifies the above steps into a single command that can download/checkout, patch, configure, build, test. This would probably be simpler for what you need than manually creating the steps with `add_custom_*` commands.